# Asp.net-MVC Custom Validation - NULL vs Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

For security and consistency I would like to test on post-back if a field is missing?  In Java (servlets in particular) when we perform a `request.getParameter(key)` the result is either a String value or otherwise NULL if the field is missing.  In MVC I've created a custom validation that I call "ThrowOnNull". The behavior I'm trying to capture is: If an intended field is missing (null) I want to throw, otherwise return success.

Consider this Custom Validator (that doesn't work):

```
public class ThrowOnNull: ValidationAttribute
{
   public ThrowOnNull() { }

   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {            
       if (value == null)
           throw new Exception(validationContext.MemberName + " field expected, but missing."));            

       return ValidationResult.Success;
   }
}
```

**Is it possible to do what I want here?**  (this validator doesn't work as expected and it's because the framework is assigning NULL to an empty value [oh dear].)

**UPDATE**: Per **@emodendroket**, the following code example now works as expected:

```
public class ThrowOnMissing: ValidationAttribute
{
    public ThrowOnMissing() { }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(validationContext.MemberName))
            throw new Exception(validationContext.MemberName + " field expected, but missing.");

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I've cleaned up the question and example code significantly to make it all much clearer, hope it helps.

Comment: I fail to understand how the answer you accepted solves the problem you are so adamant about....

Comment: In short: It solves it because it explains how it's possible to what I want. Which is: Check the raw incoming transmission for consistency though a custom validator. Further: Ensuring the incoming data (fields) are what my application expects. If not, throw, log and redirect. This technique peeks over the framework (and any reliance on it) looking at the raw stream allowing me to provide a preemptive (pre-binding) examination and certification. I welcome a MVC approach if a reasonable one is offered or explained (which hasn't been). Otherwise, I'll peek over the framewk and validate it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your own validator you can look at the dictionary `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form`.  You can then do what you've proposed with this code:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("prop"))
  {
    throw new Exception();
  }
```

Comment: The problem here is that you won't get to execute this code until after full validation has occurred by the model binder.  So your requirement to abort validation is not satisfied by this approach.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Well, now that you mention it, you're right about that, since by the time you're inside your action the model is already bound.  Putting this inside a custom model binder presumably would work.  You could even just have a model binder inheriting from the default and reflect over all the properties with the attribute and throw if any of their keys are missing before then passing to the base method.

Comment: You wouldn't need to put this code in a custom model binder, because the binder already is using reflection to go over all the properties and compare them to the properties of the posted objects.  And, indeed, your conclusion is exactly what I described in my post.

Comment: "The problem here is that you won't get to execute this code until after full validation has occurred" -- is this true even if I'm using a Custom Validator and throwing at that instant?

Comment: Cleaned up the question and code examples to make it much clearer and included an example that does work per @emodendroket.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing one important point - when you submit a form, all fields belonging to that form get submitted. If the user doesn't fill them, they're blank, so the validation for null can't really work like this...

You should probably redefine what "missing value" means.

EDIT:
After some discussion it seems you're not really concerned about null values, but about the security (false forms with missing fields and stuff like that). In that case you should simply use the standard - antiforgery token and maybe check the origin of the request. You should be more than fine this way. Checking for missing fields won't help a bit, because attacker can easily send those fields as well.

> Over/Under posting is a real concern. Furthermore, if fields aren't submitted (due to a hack or DOS attack of some kind)

Not really.

Overposting is handled by the action method on the controller. It won't accept more parameters than you've specified.

Underposting will be handled pretty much the same way as if you didn't fill the text fields in the form, again a non-issue if you have validated your model correctly.

DDOS attack can't be prevented a believe me, some checking for missing fields won't help a bit if someone has a network powerful enough to cause DDOS. Just look up latest cases on attacks and you'll understand, that if HUGE servers can't withstand that, you certainly can't prevent it like this.

Your data validation shouldn't be too expensive either. It's a web, people don't like to wait too much.

Comment: All fields belonging to that form do not exist if someone (a hacker) submits only a subset of the fields. The point of the check is to actually confirm that ALL expected fields have indeed been passed back. This is a security, consistency check. Its intended to thwart/log and report unexpected behavior.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell Frankly, this is not really a serious security measure so I wouldn't think of it that way... a hacker could easily look and see what fields your form sends and it wouldn't take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: I disagree. Over/Under posting is a real concern. Furthermore, if fields aren't submitted (due to a hack or DOS attack of some kind) then doing this sort of validation (and throwing) prevents further and possibly expensive validation (on the remaining fields) from occurring.

Comment: Walther -- Required attribute isn't enough, that's why I created the custom attribute.  Required attribute returns "Field Required" even if the field is missing altogether. That's because it's counting NULL as an Empty.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell What I mean is it's absolutely trivial to bypass, so you need something stronger to back it up.

Comment: Agreed - a `required` attribute and a well defined, bound view model are the way to go here - if the fields aren't sent, or too many fields are set the binding will throw, preventing "further and possibly expensive validation", and if the field is sent, but is empty the required attribute will catch it (but won't prevent further validation as you probably want to tell the user about all the problems, rather than one at a time...)

Comment: Zhaph: "if the fields aren't sent, or too many fields are set the binding will throw ..." -- this actually doesn't happen. If I mark Required and omit (comment out) my field in the view and post back, the binding doesn't throw, but instead simply shows it as a validation error "Field is Required". I did test this before I posted the question -- wink.

Comment: emodendroket: "What I mean is it's absolutely trivial to bypass..." do you mean that because of the Model layer, which provides the Properties regardless if post-back does or not?

Comment: `but instead simply shows it as a validation error "Field is Required"` and what else would you expect from a validation?? If you're having troubles with some hackers, this would prevent maybe some 15yo-wannabe-hackers and even there I have some doubt. If you're concerned about XSS, creating malicious forms or something like that, you should use techniques that were designed for that kind of stuff (using tokens, checking origin of the request if it's the same etc). That kind of stuff. Checking for null won't help a bit.

Comment: walther: "what else would you expect from a validation" there are different forms of validation. There's user input validation and there's system/data error consistency and validation. Each has their place. Consistency ensures that what comes across the wire is what I expect and if it isn't, someone is either screwing w/my site or I have an error somewhere. These kinds of errors aren't for end users and are best dealt with the instant that happen to avoid other possible exploits or problems. While I agree the threat of this sort is low, it does occur.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell, and why exactly you refuse to use antiforgery token and checking of the origin of the POST request? I somewhat fail to see what would accomplish if you could find the missing fields. If you use standard security approaches, you're more than fine.

Comment: antiforgery token is merely a random string that can be copied and re-CURL'd back to the site. It doesn't validate data or member consistency whatsoever. It's a half-measure and good for thwarting amateurs.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell If I were going to send an automated POST the first thing I'd do is examine what actually gets sent when I use the Web page normally.  Wouldn't you?

Comment: @JasonCaldwell I think that this method is weaker than the antiforgery token.  At least with the antiforgery token I have to mimic some browser-like behavior.

Comment: "At least with the antiforgery token I have to mimic some browser-like behavior" -- super easy to do with CURL.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell, funny that you think using antiforgery token is super easy to bypass, but you consider checking for missing fields a superior solution. Erik Funkenbusch said pretty much the same, but elaborated on the topic a bit more. Asp.net has many built-in security features and your fear seems to come from java world. .NET is very flexible as well, probably more than you currently see. If you don't agree with us and still want to reinvent the wheel, no problem.

Comment: You seem to be comparing the antif token to field consistency checking, as if one is better than the other -- I don't understand this reasoning. It's not a competition. We use all available or all appropriate measures. Antif token + Field Consist checks + Data validation + Client Input Validation and so on. I find this debate with you guys really strange and it's no wonder to me now why MS websites are hacked so much, clearly if this is the attitude and approach you guys take. Dependency or Trust of the "security" goings on behind the ASP.NET curtain, you guys should all really know better.

Comment: And as for the Antif token -- try it yourself. Copy the token out, construct a half measure form with it and post it back. But I gotta say (as an extension of what I just said) -- if that's your line of defense, LOL on you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655144/asp-net-mvc-does-antiforgerytoken-prevent-the-user-from-changing-posted-form-v

Comment: @JasonCaldwell, you laugh at me (what a mature thing of you to do, but OK), yet your solution is to check for a missing field to prevent a hack. Wow, I must admit I'm really stunned from your reasoning. I've updated the answer an hour ago, take it or leave it. This is really not a place for prolonged debates and I think me and Erik have already said enough on this matter.

Comment: Walther: you fail to see the bigger picture. it isn't just checking for a missing field, its checking for missing fields (under posts), field array bounds (over posts). This technique is used SIMPLY to detect any inconsistency. That is all. Think about it like this, say you have an array of fields and your site is set up to handle a count of 5, but then say a hacker generates 1000 fields in an DOS attempt or attempt to break/exploit. Wouldn't YOU wanna know about it? Wouldn't you wanna throw and log on such an event? Honestly, you guys need to get a grip.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell Yes, but scripting it at least requires looking at the page each time.  On the other hand, the field consistency is just a copy-and-paste job from Fiddler or whatever and once I have the correct form I can just POST as many times as I want.  I'm not against security, but this is like securing your house by putting masking tape on the door.

Comment: emodendroket: you're misunderstanding. please read my comments to Walther to clear up any misconceptions you may have.

Comment: walther: i just saw you edits. my comments here still stand and there does seem to be some misunderstanding of intent and purpose for my technique. I would also add that this isnt a measure to prevent DOS attacks (I hope you don't think me so naive), but what it does do is limit the impact on the system should one occur by over-post. Expensive validation means simply validation that might occur against (say) an SQL server or other external IO. Underpost isn't just merely not filling in the form field(s), and overpost also includes array bounds.

Comment: It's a technique to test for unusual or unexpected activity or behavior on or against your application. It is one of many techniques used. It isn't so much a security measure (although it is) as much as a way to thwart, throw, log and redirect on a specific series of attacks OR inconsistencies. This isn't in lieu of using other techniques, but instead used in conjunction with other techniques to harden your online application. I hope (finally) this clears up any confusion you have on the matter.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell I just noticed your comment here but I don't think it would make sense to validate your viewmodel against an external data store is the first place.  If that's what you're after the more usual approach is to check ModelState.IsValid in your controller before you start looking at the database (in code that exists apart from the usual MVC form validation stuff).  In this context "validation" really only refers to the form-level validation.  If the throwing attribute works for you no problem but I think you and walther are talking about different things.

Comment: "I think you and walther are talking about different things" -- agree. ModelState.IsValid + SQL/external IO -- appreciate that, helpful. Coming from Java, ASP.NET MVC is a quite a departure. Picking it up very quickly however, trying to conform to the correct way of coding in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're being unreasonably paranoid here about things.  Note that I said Unreasonably paranoid, since a little paranoia is a good thing.

First, let us analyze the "threats" and determine the risks.  You've presented several arguments:

1. Over-posting
2. Under-posting
3. Validation of empty vs null

The first item is not an issue in MVC if you are using a View Model.  You simply can't post information that the view isn't expecting (well, you can, but it's ignored).  If you're not using a view model (or not using a properly defined one) then you can use binding attributes to prevent posting of items you don't want bound.

The second, under-posting, if it's truly a concern for your model (99.999% of the time simply treating it as required is more than fine, but ok let's take your argument.  The issue here is not the validation attribute, it's the model binder.  You simply have to register a custom model binder that looks for missing values in your view model and throws if they are null.  This is easily accomplished by reflecting over the bound model and comparing it to the posted values, then throw.

The problem with your RequiredThrowIfNull approach is.. what if it's not required and it's under posted?  That's still an error according to your argument.

Finally, validation of empty vs null... you talk about expensive validation... I don't know what kind of expensive validation you could be talking about here, but server side there is noting in attributes that could be considered expensive.

The reason your attribute doesn't work is because validation attributes are called within a try/catch block by the framework already, and if it's null it's the very mechanism that treats it like empty (this mechanism also does things like catching parsing errors when a type is incorrect, such as characters in a datetime field.)

.NET is not Java, even though it largely works similarly... trying to re-implement Java patterns in .NET is going to lead to misery on your part because many basic philosophies are just different.

Even if we accept your argument of wanting to catch errors or be notified of hacking attempts, throwing is the wrong thing to do in most cases.  Instead, just log the information from the model binder and continue on as normal.  Only throw if you absolutely need to abort the request, and most of the time that simply isn't the case, even if you're being hacked... throwing will just cause the attacker to vary their attack until they no longer get the exception.

Frankly, this is an over-engineered, solution looking for a problem and there are many good .net specific ways of dealing with the REAL issues you are trying to solve.

Comment: I largely disagree. Not enough room here to take you point by point, but as I said to Walther: "there are different forms of validation. There's user input validation and there's system/data error consistency and validation. Each has their place. Consistency ensures that what comes across the wire is what I expect and if it isn't, someone is either screwing w/my site or I have an error somewhere. These kinds of errors aren't for end users and are best dealt with the instant that happen to avoid other possible exploits or problems. While I agree the threat of this sort is low, it does occur"

Comment: Furthermore, I understand the distinction between Java and ASP-MVC and I'm not trying to roll one over the other. I do however expect to be able to tell if what I expect is consistent with what I emit. And certainly not over paranoid, but having said that -- this is a Microsoft project.

Comment: I am merely security conscious, having worked with hundreds of poorly written websites and having to had fixed hundreds of hacks. Ensuring consistency goes a long way to a secure site and reduced system overhead should an exploit otherwise occur.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell - I suggest you reread what I wrote, since you seem to be arguing against something you perceive I said, not what I did.  My point is that the things you view as a security flaw in Java are generally not in ASP.NET because they are designed to mitigate those situations and they have mechanisms to deal with them, but you want to bypass all that and do something java-like which is the wrong thing to do.  Specifically, read my last sentence clearly.

Comment: I'm arguing against your overall point (or points). Furthermore, I never made claim that in Java it's a flaw, if you asked I would say quite the contrary, the flexibility Java affords in this area and several others is quite excellent. In Java a lot ISN'T done for you, which means you know what its doing because you coded it. While you claim that ASP.NET is designed to mitigate "those" situations, you offer no explanation as to how. I encourage you to re-read my original post and also the link enclosed within. Testing a NULL for a NULL isn't exclusive to Java, so get over the Java kick.

Comment: The answer is made on ASP.NET site which concisely states "by default MVC transforms empty string to null string": http://forums.asp.net/t/2006146.aspx?Custom+Validation+and+NULL

Comment: That's all I needed to read after my question "Is it possible to do what I want here?"

Answer (score 0):

**@ignatandrei** from **ASP.NET** answered the question:

> by default MVC transforms empty string to null string.

http://forums.asp.net/t/2006146.aspx?Custom+Validation+and+NULL

Comment: I don't think that affects Request.Form... was there a reason you didn't like that solution?  Like, you could look at AllKeys and see fi the key isn't there.

Comment: Please explain what you mean?  I don't think you understand my original question or this answer.

Comment: `if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("prop")){throw new Exception();}`

Comment: Basically you're bypassing MVC and model binding altogether and just looking at the form.

Comment: Well, I don't think I'm bypassing Model Binding and certainly not altogether. I'm merely looking at a value the Binder uses, yes?

Comment: Sorry if the way I stated it was confusing; what I mean is your answer here is talking about what happens after model binding; I'm saying you can get around this behavior by looking directly at the form data yourself.  Yes, it's true that the form data is used by the model binder too.

Comment: BTW: Thank you for that example code!  That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do "get around" the Model to the Form data directly. I was hoping I could achieve this without needing to do that, but the answer ignatandrei on ASP.NET (above) did confirm my original question. Your answer here however improves upon the Request.Form idea by allowing that check to indeed occur either in the Model or a Custom Validator.

Comment: I was trying to hint at that before but I edited my answer to be clearer.  Anyway, hope that helps you.

Comment: Updated my post. If you remove the empty string stuff from your answer above and leave the answer you commented on here, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: A better solution is to pass FormsCollection to your action method, which does the same thing except it's passed as a parameter.  ie: `public ActionResult Index(FormsCollection collection) {}`

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=true)]`, and if any of your model fields are in fact null then you know they were missing, and not simply empty.  I really fail to understand how this answers the question though, given all your other requirements...

Comment: Hey Erik. The point of the technique is to catch preemptively inconsistencies in the incoming transmission, to ensure the coming data (fields) are consistent with what my application expects. To the throw, log and redirect avoiding further validations from occurring should a problem be detected.

Comment: I'm not clear on AllowEmptyStrings. I looked it up after Emodendroket suggested it. It doesn't appear to be what I want, can you please confirm its purpose or how it would be used?

Comment: @JasonCaldwell - The point of AllowEmptyStrings in your case is that if the string is empty, then value will be "", if it's missing value will be null.  This is the behavior your original code was assuming to be the case, and failing because value was null for empty strings.

Comment: Ok, that's not clear in the description which states: "When you set AllowEmptyStrings to true for a data field, Dynamic Data does not perform validation and transforms the empty string to a null value."

Comment: @JasonCaldwell - that's for DynamicData, which also uses these attributes as well... MVC doesn't do that.  You would also want to set `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]` on the property as well if you're using any EditorFor's

Comment: Brilliant. I'll look into those.